# Weird outcome when sorting an array of arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Okay, just learning JavaScript here, I know I should search for the answer, but I can't even figure out what I should search for, im completely lost as to why this is happening

```
  // string or array
 var strr=[1,5,3];
//changed array.
var cha=[];
var t=0;
/*push strr into the cha array
should look like
[
[1,5,3],
[1,5,3],
[1,5,3]
]
*/
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
cha.push(strr);
}
//shuffle each element one by one
for(a in cha){
cha[a]=cha[a].sort(function()
    {return Math.floor(Math.random()*100)-50;
    });
}
//each element should be a re arranged array with the     same elemnts of strr
// Like 135, 351, 153 for example
console.log(cha);

// But it arranges all of the elements the same. the shuffle     changed the order of strr, but not each of cha...
// Like 351,351,351 for example, they are randomized, but all the same.
```

Comment: the array cha, is holding three references to the same array strr.  if you want three separate strr arrays you need to clone them.  cha.push(strr.slice(0));

Answer (score 3):

You are effectively **pushing the same array thrice**.

`push` a hollow copy of it (since it is an array of primitives)

```
cha.push( strr.slice() );
```

**Demo**

```js
var strr = [1, 5, 3];
var cha = [];
var t = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  cha.push(strr.slice());
}
for (a in cha) {
  cha[a] = cha[a].sort(function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) - 50;
  });
}
console.log(cha);
```